# Is there software that will convert a jpg to a vector format?

Tags: images, conversion, vector-graphics

Is there software that will convert a jpg image to a vector image? I've got a simple logo that is being put onto baloons/pens/whatnot and the printer needs the logo in a vector format, which we don't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home)

> Convert bitmap images like JPEGs, GIFs and PNGs to the crisp, clean, scalable vector art of EPS, SVG, and PDF with the world's best auto-tracing software.

Answer (score 2):

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (a nice free-software vector drawing software) has built-in tracing capabilities.

Just import a bitmap (File/Import Bitmap...), the choose Path/Trace Bitmap. I've used it successfully to trace an image for printing on T-Shirts.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Corel DRAW to do that (probably too big to your task).

If it is just one simple logo, I would manually recreate it directly in vector format - automated conversion will never achieve that perfect results. Than you have it forever in scalable, high quality format.