# Paper image to vector image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics

I have a paper image (image wrote on a piece of paper) which I need to edit as same as I can edit vector graphics. As I am not good with graphics, I do not know which steps to take to make it digital and convert it to vector.

So, the steps I may take are:
1. shot it via digital camera
2. convert it to vector

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Related:  [How to convert poor quality bitmap image to vector?](http://superuser.com/questions/79172/how-to-convert-poor-quality-bitmap-image-to-vector), and [Is there software that will convert a jpg to a vector format?](http://superuser.com/questions/124204/is-there-software-that-will-convert-a-jpg-to-a-vector-format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your scan or picture, you want to be using Adobe Illustrator. It has a feature called "live trace" which will generate a vector from an image.

There are lots of tutorials out there, here is a top result from google:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/15/illustrator-s-live-trace-sketch-to-vector/

video tutorial:
http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-tip-make-vector-silhouettes-with-live-trace-and-photoshop/

Comment: There are also other vector drawing products that can trace bitmaps e.g. Corel Draw and [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html)